# from tex source file jump to pdf in Texlipse

Tags: forward-inverse-search, texlipse

In TexWorks, it is easy to jump between tex source and pdf files. In Texlipse, jump from pdf to source is easily clicking the part of pdf file, but what is the symmetric easy way to jump from tex file to the corresponding part of pdf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to install **Pdf4Eclipse** plugin e.g. from here: http://borisvl.github.com/Pdf4Eclipse

Then open both the tex and the corresponding pdf file in Eclipse. Place the cursor somewhere in the tex source and open the context menu by right-clicking. Select **Forward search** menu item near the bottom.

[image: Pdf4Eclipse Forward search]